# How can I get customer on mobile app development?

Tags: working-from-home

I have been a Software developer for 3 years doing Android development and have done 6 months of professional React-Native (Android-iOS) development.

I can not seem to find a freelance Android development job -- because people don't want to pay well enough.

I tried upwork.com, but I was banned from there because I made too many offers and didn't get any customers.

I tried freelancer.com, but at freelancer there are many Indian developers, driving the bids down very low, which lowers the prices.

I tried android groups on Facebook.com, but on those groups, people will not pay enough money. They talk to you about their needs, take my solutions, and then they don't reply or answer when I send them an offer.

So what can I do to find a good freelance job on Android or iOS development?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4):

While starting your career on Upwork, Fiverr or Freelancer, you need to keep your pricing a bit low at the start as you acquire your first clients. And no one is going to give a large project to someone who is just starting out.  Once you have proven yourself with enough clients, you will be able to successfully increase your bidding prices, and they will pay you.

Considering Android and iOS, you should be able to find more than enough work on these platforms if you have good reviews from a few clients. And you should be able to earn a decent paycheck after that, since many other freelancers are earning a good living doing full-time freelancing.

Answer (score 4):

From my experience, you have to change the way you think from how do I get a job building apps to... first,  think about which businesses already have enough income to afford to pay you the kind of income you need, and second, what problems can you solve for that business building out an app for them. How will that business make more money from your app?  Studying how they currently run their business and seeing how an app can help make them more money has always been a super easy sell. Any business that is currently making money typically has no problem sharing additional income if you can figure a unique way to generate it for them through technology.  But be careful. Choosing your clients wisely is a very important part of being a sane freelance developer. I turn down gigs all the time if the owner or contact is difficult to deal with or their business doesn't already generate enough income to invest in an application. You should always choose clients that will never have a problem paying you if you are able to provide a good product. Finally, always remember to look for opportunities in a gig that will provide residual income. This has been a key to running my business. Hosting, monthly maintenance, updates, continuous development, percentage on sales, referrals, etc.. 
These key points will almost guarantee you endless gigs and success in any level. Be creative not only in your development but also in how you can help other businesses make even more money.